# How to obtain a numbers with decimals or dashes within text?

Tags: r, regex, string

Hi I have a small question?

I have a document which has text similar to:

```
Hi, my name is John Doe and I would like a new xds 6543.21-M for blah blah 
blah. I would also like hre 350-M for blah blah blah.
```

I would like to return:

```
6543.21-M

350-M
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @J.Doe was any of the answers helpful to you?

Comment: Yes, they were. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make good use of [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html)'s [str_extract_all](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_extract.html) function:

```
x <- "Hi, my name is John Doe and I would like a new xds 6543.21-M for blah blah
blah. I would also like hre 350-M for blah blah blah."
#install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, '[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?-M')
#[1] "6543.21-M" "350-M"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split the string, and then use `grep` to retrieve the element with numbers. `lapply` can allow us to apply the `grep` function over the list.

```
vec <- c("Hi, my name is John Doe and I would like a new xds 6543.21-M for blah blah", 
         "blah. I would also like hre 350-M for blah blah blah.")

list1 <- strsplit(vec, split = " ")
list2 <- lapply(list1, function(x) grep("[0-9]+", x, value = TRUE))
list2
# [[1]]
# [1] "6543.21-M"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "350-M"
```